# Spring Cloud Kubernetes fails setting ConfigMap values

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, yaml, configmap

I am trying to support K8s `ConfigMap` API using Spring to handle my externalized configuration. I've been using a configuration service without any issues, so I don't believe it is a cloud-config implementation problem. I am using version `1.0.2.RELEASE` of `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config`.

My `ConfigMap` consists of two configurations: global (application.yml) and app-specific yaml (myapp.yml). Here is what that looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myapp-config
data:
  application.yml: |-
    kafka:
      hosts: kafka:9092

      topics:
        events: myapp-events
        normalized: myapp-normalized
        #...

    storage:
      uri: mongodb://mongo-0.mongo:27017,mongo-1.mongo:27017,mongo-2.mongo:27017
      database: do-stuff-db
      #...

    spring:
      cloud:
        config:
          override-system-properties: false

    #...

  myapp.yml: |-
    myapp:
      broadcast-address: 0.0.0.0:666

      #...
```

`application.yml` seems to work just fine. I can see the configuration values in my application but for whatever reason, `myapp.yml` does not get set. I can see Spring is successfully grabbing the entire result from the `ConfigMap` API but it does not do anything with `myapp.yml`.

Turning on debug logging exposed how Spring is interpreting the `ConfigMap` result. It is treating the entire `myapp.yml` section as one property and not its own property source. This explains why the `application.yml` is taking and not the `myapp.yml`. Here is what that log looks like (I have truncated the message):

```
2019-09-04 14:01:37.083 [main] INFO  config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='composite-configmap', propertySources=[ConfigMapPropertySource@92864491 {name='configmap.myapp-config.default', properties={kafka.hosts=kafka:9092, kafka.topics.events=myapp-events, kafka.topics.normalized=myapp-normalized, myapp.yml=myapp:
  bind-address: 0.0.0.0:666

  #...

    storage.uri: mongodb://mongo-0.mongo:27017,mongo-1.mongo:27017,mongo-2.mongo:27017, storage.database: do-stuff-db}}]}
```

Do I need to separate these configurations? The examples I've seen from Spring suggest you could consolidate your configuration into a single YAML `ConfigMap` file. I am stumped.

Comment: u can try via envrionment variable

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni I don't understand your comment. Try what through an environment variable?

Comment: You can follow this link, i fixed this for my project using the first option https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-spring-boot-on-kubernetes-with-configm